# Get key if element matches one of the list items

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has list of strings as values:

```py
components = {
    'skin': [
        'first',
        'second',
        'third',
    ],
    'hair': [
        'fourth',
        'fifth',
    ]
}
```

I want to return the key if a matching string was found in one of the lists, i.e.:

`fourth` -> returns `hair`

or

`second` -> returns `skin`

etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there always exactly one matching key or can there be zero and multiple?

Comment: `next(k for k, v in components.items() if some_item in v)`

Comment: @JiříBaum I tried just a regular for loop, iterating over items like Olvin. I was wondering if there might be an operator or some other clever built-in method to do that.

Comment: @MateuszWójt, if you need to perform this search on same dictionary continuously it could be a good idea to construct reverse dictionary.

Comment: Nope, no particular trick; this is really the reverse of the way a dictionary is intended to be used, so there aren't any tricks. As @OlvinRoght suggests, if you need to do it a lot of times on the same dictionary, constructing the reverse dictionary could be more efficient (but it'd cost something to construct it, so you'd have to judge or measure based on your situation).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> def fnd_key(dct, srch_wrd):
...    for k,v in dct.items():
...        if srch_wrd in v:
...            return k

>>> components = {'skin': ['first', 'second', 'third'], 'hair': ['fourth','fifth']}

>>> fnd_key(components, 'second')
'skin'

>>> fnd_key(components, 'fourth')
'hair'
```

You can try this if `value` ***(like:second)*** exist in multi `list`:

```
>>> def fnd_key(dct, srch_wrd):
...    for k,v in dct.items():
...        if srch_wrd in v:
...           yield k

>>> components = {'skin': ['first', 'second', 'third'], 
                  'hair': ['fourth','fifth', 'second']}
>>> for ky in fnd_key(components, 'second'):
...    print(ky)

skin
hair
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the in keyword.

```
for key in components.keys():
    if search in components[key]:
        print(key)
```

Beware that, the time complexity of in depends on the container.

- list - Average: O(n)
- set/dict - Average: O(1), Worst: O(n)

Comment: Iterating over `components.keys()` is bad idea as well ass access to value of key you're iterating over using this key. Use `for key, values in components.items()` and `if search in values`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a search algorithm but repeating the search many times is inefficient. If your values in the sublists are unique, you should reverse and flatten your dictionary.

```
>>> components_rev = {v:k for k, values in components.items() for v in values}
>>> components_rev
{'first': 'skin', 'second': 'skin', 'third': 'skin', 'fourth': 'hair', 'fifth': 'hair'}
>>> components_rev['fourth']
'hair'
```

Comment: If values are not unique it could be an option to apply [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap): `ChainMap(*({v: k for v in values} for k, v in components.items()))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print([k for k,v in components.items() if 'fourth' in v][0])
```

Comment: No need to continue search after one key found, so will be more efficient to pass generator to `next()` rather than construct whole list and retrieve just first value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
components = {
    'skin': [
        'first',
        'second',
        'third',
        ],
    'hair': [
        'fourth',
        'fifth',
    ]
}

def find_key(myDict, value):
    for key in myDict:
        if value in myDict[key]:
            return key
    return -1
    
print(find_key(components, 'fourth'))
```